# DateTime Json Return From WebAPI with Default Serializer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I know this question has been hashed over multiple times and I read lots of posts on that hashing but still am confused.

Using MVC4/WebAPI, I have a datetime that is simply created as new DateTime.Now.

My WebAPI is return data like this:

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
            {
                data = sessionRecordSmalls,
                count = sessionRecordSmalls.Count,
                success = true
            });
```

where sessionRecordsSmall has a public property of DateTime in it.

When I look at the date in the VS debugger, it shows it as now with no timezone of course because DateTime does not include a timezone.

{10/6/2012 9:45:00 AM}

When I look at what gets downloaded from the server, I see in the JSON

2012-10-06T09:45:00

I think the T0 means Timezone 0, not 100% sure of that.  My JavaScript library interprets it as timezone 0, then shows the actual date downloaded as GMT (-9 hours ago for me).

My question is, what is the JSON downloaded? Is that include a timezone?  Am I missing some important step here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The date time `2012-10-06T09:45:00`, which we recive in JSON with Web API and default serializer is [the ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

In fact this is so called [Combined date and time representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations). Extract:

> ..A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a
>   complete date expression, the letter T as a delimiter, and a valid
>   time expression. For example "2007-04-05T14:30"...

There is no time zone information in this format. As mentioned in the [Time zone designators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) Extract:

> Time zones in ISO 8601 are represented as local time (with the
>   location unspecified), as UTC, or as an offset from UTC.  If no UTC
>   relation information is given with a time representation, the time is
>   assumed to be in local time.

In other words, if there is no offset from UTC specified, it is treated as a local time.

The [UTC format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) would be extended with `Z` at the end

> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a
>   space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC"
>   is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would
>   be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".

*UTC time is also known as 'Zulu' time, since 'Zulu' is the NATO phonetic alphabet word for 'Z'.*

So, the date-time we recieve is the ISO 8601 format, treated as local time zone *(no `Z` at the end like this `2012-10-06T09:45:00Z`)*

Comment: I notice that when I decorate my datetime with:  [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
            public DateTime LogDate { get; set; } I get what I expect with the conversion, should that not be the default?

Comment: Honestly not sure ... but I would suggest to read this http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.cz/2012/04/beg-steal-or-borrow-decent-javascript.html ... I am doing conversion into UTC also with some hacking

Answer (score 49):

if serializing with json.net keep in mind that you can specify [DateTimeZoneHandling](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm).

Example in WebApiConf.cs

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling =Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```