# DateTimeOffset is parsed incorrectly in WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I have the problem that when I send my json-object to my API, the DateTime is reset by one hour. I already read that I should use DateTimeOffset. I did that too, but I get the same result. An example of what my object looks like:

```
{
    "Person": {
        "Birthday": "2000-01-26T00:00:00+01:00"
    }
}
```

So everything is correct, but as soon as the object is transferred to the API, the object looks like this:

```
{
    "Person": {
        "Birthday": "2000-01-25T23:00:00+00:00"
    }
}
```

To get the data I saved it like this:

```
Person person = new Person
{
  Birthday = DateTimeOffset.Parse(row["Birthday"].ToString())
}
```

Comment: All times are in Utc, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697346/datetime-json-return-from-webapi-with-default-serializer

Comment: Read the similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933654/convert-utc-datetime-to-datetimeoffset

Comment: So I need the ISO8601 Format which look like this: `2000-01-26T00:00:00Z`?